# How to count entries based on timestamp

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count how many entries with a particular timestamp or range are in my table and although it’s pretty simple, I cannot find the proper way to do that.

Example data:

```
A
------------------
9/12/2011 11:08:40
4/23/2012 8:09:22
4/23/2012 8:11:55
```

What I want to calculate is how many entries were made in 2011 and how many in 2012.

I tried to make some string checks with `countif`, like `countif(A:A, "*/2011*")`, but it does’t work.

I also tried to use the `YEAR()` function this way: `countif(A:A, year(A)="2012")`, but it returns 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(B:B));2011)`

or

`=COUNT(FILTER(B:B;YEAR(B:B)=2012))`

or

`=INDEX(QUERY(B:B;"SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE YEAR(B)=2012");2;1)`

If you use the `QUERY` formula without the `INDEX`, then a header will appear as well.

Comment: Thank you ! i eventualy found this solution : count(filter(A:A,YEAR(A:A)=2012)) which works prety well, i've even be able to build on top of it to make some sum on other cell. I realy need to dig into this ARRAYFORMULA thing.